# Multiple calls to server method in meteor on button click

Tags: meteor

On button click, server method is called. When user clicks button again before the server method completes, I want to terminate the execution of server method and restart a fresh.

Client Code:

```
Meteor.call('getData');
```

Server Method:

```
getData:function(){ 
    this.unblock(); 
    // Long running operation
}
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to cancel a method call once its started. Can you describe the actual problem in more detail? Maybe there's another solution.

Comment: Are you starting fresh because say data may have changed or because you don't want the user to execute twice. If it's the latter then just disable the button until it return from the server. If it is due to the data changing or needing to restart would need to understand more of what your method is doing to offer a solution, there isnt anything out of the box to handle this afaik

Comment: You could have a global object that is checked between each of your functions inside of your method. However, I am not sure there is a way to stop a thread immediately inside of Meteor as you are describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use async method call on client. Set a variable to store method call status. 
In callback function, you just need to set a variable to tell that method call has ended. Thus, new calls come in only if status is ended (false).

```
var methodCallIsRunning = false;

if(methodCallIsRunning)
  return;

Meteor.call('getData', function(err, result){
  methodCallIsRunning = false;
});
methodCallIsRunning = true;
```